# How to restrict access to ALB so that it reads traffic only from a Ec2 machine in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a below architecture within a non default VPC.

```
Route53 -> ALB(web server) - > Ec2 (web servers) - > ALB(application server) - > Ec2 (application server) - > RDS.
```

I want my ALB for App server to only read the traffic coming from Ec2 web servers.
I tried adding a rule in the security of ALB with source as a security group of the Ec2 web servers.

[image]
for some reason, it is not working. But when I add 0.0.0.0/0 as the source for the rules it is working.

I feel I am missing something here.
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is `ALB(application server)` internal/private ALB?

Comment: @Marcin it's internet-facing

Comment: So that's why it probably does not work. Can you double check, and use VPC cidr range instead of `0.0.0.0/0`?

Comment: @Marcin I don't want ALB application server to be internet-facing. it should be only accessible from the wen servers , sorry for the last comment

Comment: Can you please check, if it is Internet or internal/private load balancer?

Comment: schema is internet facing in the ALB details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230396/discussion-between-sumanth-shetty-and-marcin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `ALB(application server)` is **internet facing** it can only be accessed through **public IP**. This means that your `Ec2 (web servers)` are using Internet to access `ALB(application server)`:

```
Route53 -> ALB(web server) - > Ec2 (web servers) - > INTERNET -> ALB(application server) - > Ec2 (application server) - > RDS
```

In this case, your security groups (SGs) can only work with `0.0.0.0/0` rule, not by referencing web servers' SGs. SG referencing works only if traffic is **within VPCs** , not from the Internet.

In your setup, your `ALB(application server)` should be internal ALB in **private subnets**, not public ones. Since your setup follows a **three-tier architectures**, please have a look at some example designs below. Note that in all of them, the second ALB is internal and app servers are in private subnets. This allows to use SGs the way you want.

- [Designing a Three-Tier Architecture in AWS](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/designing-a-three-tier-architecture-in-aws-e5c24671f124)
- [Three Tier Architecture for Web Applications in AWS](https://www.techtruffle.com/blog/aws/three-tier-architecture/)
- [AWS – 3-Tier Web Application Architecture](https://voidopinion.wordpress.com/2017/06/13/aws-3-tier-web-application-architecture/)
- [AWS Best Practices: 3-Tier Infrastructure](https://blog.stratus10.com/aws-best-practices-3-tier-infrastructure)

Comment: ,i have two questions. 
1. how do I call the app server from the code. In case of internet-facing i used to call from the domain I gave it. Here should I use the Nat gateway IP or ?
2. How would I handle my deployment? currently it is being handled by Jenkins but once it's private how would jenkins access that?

Comment: @sumanthshetty 1. You still use domain name, but it will resolve to private IP addresses of ALB, and traffic is within VPC only. Don't need NAT for that. 2. Depends how your jenkins is setup. If it needs internet, then can use NAT. You can also setup VPC interface endponits to access AWS services, without NAT.

Comment: Could you help me out with this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951040/request-header-field-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers

Comment: Hey Marci @Marcin

Comment: @sumanthshetty Sadly, I don't know what could be wrong :-(

Comment: stuck with this. not able to figure out

Comment: @sumanthshetty Hopefully, someone else will be able to help. I'm not much of SAM user, thus I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: could you help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67428507/dns-new-alias-record-is-not-propagating-to-an-alb