# Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response when creating API through SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am creating Rest APIs with SAM template.

I am testing these APIs through Postman and everything is working as expected, but as soon I integrate these APIs in my application, I am getting this error:

```
from origin 'http://localhost:3033' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

This is happening only for PUT, POST and PATCH method. GET method is working fine.

I have added the below in the code return part:

```py
return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"},
    "body": json.dumps(item)
}
```

However, the error still shows up.

I created an API and lambda to serve the same function with the console and it was working fine with the Application.

Here is my SAM code for creating an API:

```yaml
ApiGatewaySignUpFlowUserApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name: loadeo_signup
    StageName: Stage
    Cors: "'*'"

CreateUserSignup:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: loadeo_create_user_signup
    CodeUri: createUserSignup/
    Handler: create_user_signup.lambda_handler
    Timeout: 5
    Runtime: python3.8
    Role: arn:aws:iam::272075499248:role/loadeo_lambda_execution
    MemorySize: 128
    Events:
      GetAllUser:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /create-user
          Method: post
          RestApiId:
            Ref: ApiGatewaySignUpFlowUserApi
```

I can't really understand what might be wrong here. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the API definition to below helped me solve the issue:

```yaml
ApiGatewaySignUpFlowUserApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name: loadeo_signup
    StageName: Stage
    Cors: 
      AllowMethods: "'*'"
      AllowHeaders: "'*'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
```

Explicitly specifying the CORS rule helped.

Comment: Please note that this is very bad practise. It's much saver to check the request origin, and if it matches the expected domain(s) add the cors header to the response.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/), the value for the `cors` key to permit all requests is `true` rather than `"*"`.