# DNS new Alias record is not propagating to an ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an ALB which holds my webserver.
Initially, there was a DNS record with a different hosted zone(A) attached to the ALB
14 hours back I deleted the record in the hosted zone(A) and created a new record in the hosted zone(B).

But every time I search for the record name of the hosted zone(B) the site redirects to the record of the hosted zone(A) and keep on loading.

I thought it would be propagated within an hour but it seems to be taking longer.
Any reason for this? Or am I missing any steps for this?

Comment: maybe the ttl value for previous record is not over and it still exist, did you try flusing your dns cache value in your local computer

Comment: @JatinMehrotra default TTL was for 300 sec which is 5 min. 
It has been more than 14 hours now

Comment: did you tried flushing your local dns cache?

Comment: Can you check the hosted zone(B) work or not?

Comment: Can you check from different browser or device?

Comment: If you are doing this from your home computer, sometimes your ISP might cache DNS longer than TTL. Try bring up an EC2 instance and query from there.